# new request show up when I do nothing with request monitor

Tags: mongodb, flask, flask-wtforms

I run the codes from the  book and successfully deploy it in my testing "deerdog.me" website as a portal. 
There are 3 modules to work: registration, table create and requests monitor.

the 1st user registration module is good.

but when get in with the new registered id/pwd into left-top sign-in form. (under "home" hint, to click for popup) 
you see the 2nd table_creating module seems good. create on table by each random number you input.

But the bug is here, here you should not touch with the 3rd module--request, but once you click the "dashboard" in the upper navigation bar. 
In new page, weirdly you can see a new request be stealthy added. (theoretically ,the request row can only added by "add-request" function,but not now "get-request" function.

The biggest hint I found is that I only put the "add-request" under the route of `@app.route("/newrequest/<tid>")` ,but even the route `@app.route("/account/createtable"...` ,which only has "get-request" function ,can create request in mongodb's `db.requests.()`.
Why does this happen, pls help me check and fix. Thank a lot.

Manipulation logic of 2nd module (creating table and display with the same "/account" route page ,
activate action == you input a random num(2,5 or 66,109) in blank and click "create button" ,then you will see the rows(include a shor url) in same "/account" page.
Manipulation logic of 3rd module (create requests then display in '/dashboard' route page.)  should only be activated in such scenario (user copy the short URL in /account route page's table row, then ctrl+ p the short URl to a new browse address ,then under this new "@app.route("/newrequest/") ,a request in mongodb start to legally create" ,now user can jump the manipulation logic of 3rd module. directly create request record without initiating "@app.route("/newrequest/" ,Why does this happen?

```
#dbhelper.py as below
import pymongo
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

DATABASE = "waitercaller"


class DBHelper:

    def __init__(self):
        client = pymongo.MongoClient()
        self.db = client[DATABASE]

    def add_table(self, number, owner):
        new_id = self.db.tables.insert({"number": number, "owner": owner})
        return new_id

    def update_table(self, _id, url):
        self.db.tables.update({"_id": _id}, {"$set": {"url": url}})

    def get_tables(self, owner_id):
        return list(self.db.tables.find({"owner": owner_id}))

    def get_table(self, table_id):
        return self.db.tables.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(table_id)})

    def delete_table(self, table_id):
        self.db.tables.remove({"_id": ObjectId(table_id)})

    def add_request(self, table_id, time):
        table = self.get_table(table_id)
        try:
            self.db.requests.insert({"owner": table['owner'], "table_number": table[
                                    'number'], "table_id": table_id, "time": time})
            return True
        except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
            return False

    def get_requests(self, owner_id):
        return list(self.db.requests.find({"owner": owner_id}))

    def delete_request(self, request_id):
        self.db.requests.remove({"_id": ObjectId(request_id)})
```

main APP code, called waitercaller.py

```
waitercaller.py
...
@app.route("/")
def home():
    #return "Under construction"
    #return render_template("home.html")
    #registrationform = RegistrationForm()
    return render_template("home.html", loginform=LoginForm(), registrationform=RegistrationForm())

@app.route("/dashboard")
@login_required
def dashboard():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    requests = DB.get_requests(current_user.get_id())
    for req in requests:
        deltaseconds = (now - req['time']).seconds
        req['wait_minutes'] = "{}.{}".format((deltaseconds/60), str(deltaseconds % 60).zfill(2))
    return render_template("dashboard.html", resolvesubmitform=ResolveForm(),requests=requests)

@app.route("/dashboard/resolve")
@login_required
def dashboard_resolve():
    form = ResolveForm(request.form)
    request_id = request.args.get("request_id")
    #if form.validate():
    DB.delete_request(request_id)
    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    #return render_template("dashboard.html", resolvesubmitform=ResolveForm(),requests=DB.get_requests(request_id))

@app.route("/account")
@login_required
def account():
    tables = DB.get_tables(current_user.get_id())
    return render_template("account.html", createtableform=CreateTableForm(), tables=tables)

@app.route("/account/createtable", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def account_createtable():
    form = CreateTableForm(request.form)
    if form.validate():
        tableid = DB.add_table(form.tablenumber.data, current_user.get_id())
        new_url = BH.shorten_url(config.base_url + "newrequest/" + str(tableid))
        DB.update_table(tableid, new_url)
        return redirect(url_for('account'))
    return render_template("account.html", createtableform=form, tables=DB.get_tables(current_user.get_id()))

@app.route("/account/deletetable")
@login_required 
def account_deletetable():
    tableid = request.args.get("tableid")
    DB.delete_table(tableid)
    return redirect(url_for('account'))

@app.route("/newrequest/<tid>")
def new_request(tid):
    DB.add_request(tid, datetime.datetime.now())
    return "Your request has been logged and a waiter will be with you shortly"



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: So far was not able to reproduce it

Comment: @Alex, thank for your time and attempt. I  add the manipulation logic of 2rd module and 3rd module in above "question section" , and 3rd module (create requests then display in '/dashboard' route page.) should only be activated in such scenario (user copy the short URL in /account route page's table row, then ctrl+ p the short URl to a new browse address ,then under this new "@app.route("/newrequest/") ,a request in mongodb start to legally create" ,now user can jump the manipulation logic of 3rd module. directly create request record without initiating "@app.route("/newrequest/". it's puzzle.